# Google Charts Axis Percentage

Tags: google-visualization

https://jsfiddle.net/vko75dg4/

I want to have the figure as a % but its not working for me. I also want to get rid of the time that is next to the date when your hover over the chart.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Test 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Product 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Product 2');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Product 3');      

  data.addRows([



  [new Date(2015, 01, 1),  73, 88, 96, 79],[new Date(2015, 02, 1),  100, 75, 86, 90],[new Date(2015, 03, 1),  76, 95, 93, 86],[new Date(2015, 04, 1),  95, 75, 100, 98],[new Date(2015, 05, 1),  91, 31, 88, 85],[new Date(2015, 06, 1),  90, 74, 72, 79],[new Date(2015, 07, 1),  95, 80, 90, 78],      ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'test',
      subtitle: '',
    },
    width: 1300,
    height: 600,
    vAxis: { format: 'percent' }



  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
  }
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>


<div id="linechart_material"></div>

 </body>


 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [Line Chart documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) you can tell that you need to use `chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));` in replacement of your `chart.draw(data, options);`.

Using the `%` suffix will cause some unwanted formatting though,it'll mutliply your data with 100, but you can just divide your data by 100 first.

Comment: thank you that worked!!

Any idea how to remove the time after the date when you hover over the data?

Comment: Sorry but no, I havn't worked a lot with material charts. Looking at this comparasion of classic and material chart (completely unrelated information in the charts though) you can see that they have the same scenario, with hours and minutes showing, [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/).

Comment: I figured it out .....  https://jsfiddle.net/vko75dg4/4/

added hAxis: {
                format:'MMM d, y'
            }

Why dos the chart show first date as Feb 2015 instead of Jan 2015